# generating random integer with 10 numbers always start with 1

Tags: php

i am using this code

```
<?php

function random()
{
    return rand(1111111111,9999999999);
};

for ($x = "1";$x <= "5";$x++)
{
    echo $x." : ".random()."<br>";
};
echo "<hr>";

?>
```

some outputs :

> 1 : 1303960718
>   2 : 1308203081
>   3 : 1280148745
>   4 : 1263151923
>   5 : 1124814399

i tried generating more numbers and all of it starts with 1
i tried to used rand() directly and the same thing happend

Comment: It works properly for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me on a Mac. I tried mt_rand() which produced the same results. I also clipped one digit off the two input parameters and it worked with both rand() and mt_rand(). Sounds a lot like a stack overflow problem.

Answer (score 1):

Run this code and you will get your answer yourself

```
 return rand(2147483647,9999999999);
```

Then try running

```
echo getrandmax();
```

Depending upon your system you might get something like `2147483647`

That means your upper limit is pretty much useless beyond that number. And on certain systems that max can even be lower than that. You also have to research about **[integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)** overflow.

Now if you were to go easy on your system and remove 1 digit from your number and make the new range

```
return rand(111111111,999999999);
```

Then your code **[would work just fine](https://eval.in/398684)**, because there are no overflows.